# Что нужно знать хорошему веб программисту?

Tags: веб-программирование

Читал комментарии людей, что ведь программист - не самая лучшая профессия в плане зарплаты. Хочу узнать, что нужно знать хорошему веб-программисту, а не простому php-кодеру. Нужно ли  веб программисту поучиться работать с такими языка как С++/C/pascal? Какую роль отыгрывают java и C# в веб программирование?

Тогда, после всего ниже написано, где можно уточнить, что требуется знать веб программисту. Везде пишут  php, mysql, html, javascript, css, этого достаточно или что помимо этого должен знать и уметь хороший программист?

Тогда после всего описанного ниже у меня возник еще один вопрос. А есть ли смысл веб программисту знать один из языков таких как C++, Java, C#?

Comment: Основные алгоритмы и структуры данныx, думаю, для всеx программистов актуальны.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы ожидаете полный список того, что вам необходимо знать, то вы будете огорчены.
Кстати, PHP программист от других отличается только тем, что пишет на PHP.

Изучать такие языки как Java/C#/C++, Assembler само по себе полезно для понимания многих базовых вещей. Поработав некоторое время с нескриптовыми языками, вы поймете, как работают ваши программы, узнаете, какие средства использовать для решения той или иной задачи. Это позволит писать на PHP более эффективный, гибкий код. Знание алгоритмов тоже способствует этому.

Изучив средства, фреймворки для других языков под web, вы сможете провести паралели с PHP, оценить их недостатки и преимущества. Вы можете не знать их все, но ознакомиться обязательно надо.

Это все в плане общего развития, а что касается материального: 
**хороший** программист **всегда** востребован, достаточно часто правдиво и обратное утверждение: **востребованный** програмист - **хороший**.

Можно сделать ставку на это. Ищете биржу труда, вакансии, смотрите на web SSE. Учите все то, что есть в списке требований. Как вариант можно искать сами проэкты...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, у программистов хорошая зарплата (хотя как в России, не знаю), но вообще зависит от того, с чем вы именно работаете. Во-вторых, нужно иметь интерес к этому, без него будет сложно.

Что значит, "а не простому пхп-кодеру"? На пхп можно много крутых вещей делать, если ум есть и руки прямые.

Нужно знать базы данных (они очень много где используются, особенно в интернете),
еще неплохо знать флеш, он тоже активно используется в интернете. А так же важно следить за новостями сферы IT, это поможет ориентироваться в этом быстро изменяющимся мире и видеть, где и что перспективнее.

Answer (score 0):

В плане зарплаты лучшая профессия - слуга народа, но не всем совесть позволит им стать =)

Вообще программист - термин довольно общий. Знание синтаксиса языка - вторично, при большом опыте он осваивается за неделю. Первично наличие в голове тысяч алгоритмов, а это - только опыт. Чтобы примерно оценить именно языки, можно взять три языка из совсем разных степей - ассемблер, что-то компилируемое (C++/Delphi/Java), что-то интерпретируемое (php тот же). Такой набор в принципе позволит трезво оценить задачу и подобрать решение к ней, а уже что использовать, будет зависеть от решения. Реально был проект (умер, правда, фирму закрыли), у которого веб-фронт был на php+flash, внутренности на C с асм вперемешку (чтоб было красиво и быстро) и там еще всякие библиотеки и cgi непонятного содержания.

ЗЫ: В моем окружении наблюдается какой-то недетский интерес к "standalone web server"ам, т.е. экзешникам грубо говоря. Это, конечно, не для визиток, а всякие серьезные проекты с видео-аудио, но тем не менее. Там вообще только разметка из web-привычного, остальное компилируется.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший программист должен хорошо понимать как функционирует вся инфраструктура (в т.ч. и на уровне приближенном к аппаратуре) - интернет, локальная сеть, устройства хранения, процессоры, память.

Кроме этого он должен чувствовать, что хочет (имеет в виду) заказчик (в т.ч. потенциальный).

Про языки разного уровня и алгоритмы со структурами данных Вам уже сказали.

Answer (score -1):

Считаю, что всего знать невозможно! Да и учить впрок нет смысла - забудется! Поэтому, на мой взгляд, нужно:

- уметь правильно пользоваться поиском,
- уметь правильно формулировать свои мысли.